# Import a database using AzureRM Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-database

There is a document named [Import a BACPAC file to create a new Azure SQL database using PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-import-powershell/) that covers how to import a bacpac file into SQL server under ASM.

Is there a way to import a bacpac file into an Azure SQL Server using Azure Resource Management cmdlets.

Following on from @juvchan answer I have been trying to get the following to work.

```
$update = @{
            "operationMode" = "Import"
            "storageKey"= "Key"
            "storageKeyType" = "Primary"
            "administratorLogin"= "adminlogin"
            "administratorLoginPassword"= "adminpassword"
            "storageUri"= "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/sql/exampleIOSQL-2016-1-23-12-26.bacpac"
            }
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" `
                -ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/servers" `
                -Name "sqldbsvr" `
                -PropertyObject $update `
                -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 `
                -Force -Location "westeurope"
```

Unfortunately I can't get anything but this very helpful error message -

> New-AzureRmResource : {"code":"","message":"An error occurred while processing this request.","target":null,"details":[],"innererror":[]}

Comment: Hi Michael, is using ARM Azure Rm cmdlets with ARM template acceptable for you?

Comment: @juvchan The ideal method is to find a Powershell command that will achieve this. However at the moment (as of AzureRM.v1.1.0) I suspect this is not possible but will hopefully become possible in some future version. So in the interim a template is likely the only way forward.

Comment: yes I agree with you, that's why for Rm context the current workaround is to use ARM template. Do you need the ARM template and AzureRm PowerShell cmdlet to achieve this for your acceptable answer or others?

Comment: @juvchan I largely post these sort of questions because the answers don't exist online, so if you can post an answer that could be widely understood by people who stumble on it in future.

Answer (score 4):

At current time, the latest **`Microsoft Azure PowerShell - January 2016 (version 1.1)`**'s Azure RM module **does not** have any cmdlets which 
can support Azure SQL database import like the Azure Service Management's cmdlet i.e. `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport`

However, there is a workaround which can achieve this in the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) context.

The workaround is to do a **Azure Resource Group template deployment with a user-defined ARM template which include the database import resource type**.

The proposed workaround consist of a sample PowerShell script, a sample ARM template json and a sample ARM Template parameters json as shown below:

The PowerShell sample code is as below:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$tenantId = "your_tenant_id"
$subscriptionId = "your_subscription_id"

$rgName = "your_rg_name"
$location = "your_location"
$templateFile = "YourARMTemplate.json"
$templateParamFile = "YourARMTemplate.Parameters.json"

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -TenantId $tenantId

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Location $location -Name $rgName -Force

$deployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile $templateFile -TemplateParameterFile $templateParamFile -Mode Incremental -Force
```

The sample ARM template json for Azure SQL database import is as below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {
    "dbApiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
    "resourceGroupLocation": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dbServerNameTidy": "[toLower(trim(parameters('dbServerName')))]",
    "masterDbNameTidy": "[toLower(trim(parameters('masterDbName')))]"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "dbServerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dbLogin": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dbPassword": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dbServerVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "12.0"
    },
    "dbCollation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    },
    "dbEdition": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "dbMaxSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10737418240"
    },
    "dbServiceObjectiveLevel": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "455330E1-00CD-488B-B5FA-177C226F28B7"
    },
    "bacpacStorageKey": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "masterDbName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "masterBacpacUrl": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('dbApiVersion')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
        "version": "[parameters('dbServerVersion')]"
      },
      "name": "[variables('dbServerNameTidy')]",
      "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "apiVersion": "[variables('dbApiVersion')]",
          "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          },
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('dbServerNameTidy'))]"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "databases",
          "apiVersion": "[variables('dbApiVersion')]",
          "properties": {
            "edition": "[parameters('dbEdition')]",
            "collation": "[parameters('dbCollation')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('dbMaxSize')]",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveId": "[parameters('dbServiceObjectiveLevel')]"
          },
          "name": "[variables('webDbNameTidy')]",
          "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('dbServerNameTidy'))]"
          ],
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "extensions",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('dbApiVersion')]",
              "properties": {
                "operationMode": "Import",
                "storageKey": "[parameters('bacpacStorageKey')]",
                "storageKeyType": "Primary",
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
                "storageUri": "[parameters('masterBacpacUrl')]"
              },
              "name": "Import",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('dbServerNameTidy'), variables('masterDbNameTidy'))]"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The sample ARM template parameters json for Azure SQL database import is as below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "dbServerName": {
            "value": "<your DB Server Name>"
        },
        "dbLogin": {
            "value": "<Your DB server login name>"
        },
        "dbPassword": {
            "value": "<Your DB server login password>"
        },
        "bacpacStorageKey": {
            "value": "<Your Azure Storage Account Primary key which stores the bacpac blob>"
        },
        "masterDbName": {
            "value": "<your Azure Sql Db name>"
        },
        "masterBacpacUrl": {
            "value": "<Your Azure storage account Bacpac blob file full Url>"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and clarifies.

Comment: That's a good answer! Thank you. I am wondering whether it would be possible to use a snippet of that within a `New-AzureRmResource` PropertyObject though (so that just the restore can be done via template)

Comment: Juv, this is very useful information.  I intend to put the bacpac into a public container.  The template failed without the storagekey and storagetype properties, it also failed if I set the storagekey to "Anonymous".  Do you know a solution for my case?

Comment: Hi @JonathanGao, thanks very much for your compliment. Are you able to create a new question on this so it also benefits other community members?

Comment: I have found the solution for my question. I have created a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776888/import-databases-using-azure-arm-template/35776889#35776889