# Import databases using Azure ARM template

Tags: sql, database, templates, azure, azure-resource-manager

Using Azure ARM template, you can create Azure SQL databases.  But how can you deploy table schemas or import databases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and a sample ARM template can be found at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987911/import-a-database-using-azurerm-powershell/34989636#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987911/import-a-database-using-azurerm-powershell/34989636#_=_)

The following is an example of using a public container instead of a private container:

"storageKey": "?",
   "storageKeyType": "SharedAccessKey",
   "storageUri": "[variables('bacpacURL')]"